# Limiting results from Vue for-loop to only the currently used one

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, for-loop, dynamic

I'm using a for-loop to get all of my `posts` and then using a partial to get a list of all the `usersThatUpvoted` that post.

```
<div v-for="p in posts" style="padding: 16px">
    <div>
        <%- partial('../../partials/upvoter') %>
    </div>                
</div>
```

This is what's in the partial:

```
<div style="background-color: white;padding: 16px;
display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    {{p.usersThatUpvoted}}
</div>
```

It's almost working properly. So, when I click on the first post, I get the `usersThatUpvoted` that `post`:
[image: First Post Upvoters]

And when I click on the second post, I get the `usersThatUpvoted` that `post`:
[image: Second Post Upvoters]

I just want to eliminate the other unused arrays.

This post seemed to focus on a specific item in the index:
[How to put class="active" to first element in vuejs for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487711/how-to-put-class-active-to-first-element-in-vuejs-for-loop)

I'd like it to be dynamic to which one's active (don't know if that's the right term). Also when I tried using "active" , I get the error:

> Property or method "active" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should look into [conditional rendering](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html)

I'm assuming that when you select a certain post, only the upvoters of such post will be available

This won't render the empty arrays :

```
<div v-for="p in posts" style="padding: 16px">
    <div v-if="p.usersThatUpvoted.length > 0">
        <%- partial('../../partials/upvoter') %>
    </div>                
</div>
```

Comment: okay so that works for the first selection (i got really excited lol) but then once I try clicking on another post it shows both arrays. I only want it to show the currently clicked array

Comment: i'm definitely going to read up on the conditional rendering right now, thanks for that!

Comment: Ok so my assumption was wrong :'D
Try to add a property like p.shouldShowUpvoted and add it inside the condition like so ```p.usersThatUpvoted.length > 0 && p.shouldShowUpvoted```