# How can I style the first element of a v-for in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I want to set an `active` class just to first button in this code:

```html
<button
  class='optional-red-outlined-btn'
  v-for="(item, index) in faq"
  :key="item._id"
  @click="btnIndex = index"
>
  {{ item.question }} 
</button>
```

It means than when the page is loaded, if 4 buttons were in it, first of them should have `optional-red-outlined-btn` class and `active` class but others just have `optional-red-outlined-btn` class.

of course but i want when click on other button remove active of first button ,I use it for just one button have active style button:focus{ background-color: $optional-red; color: #fff; } but i want in default first button have this style

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487711/how-to-put-class-active-to-first-element-in-vuejs-for-loop)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a dynamic class based on a condition like

```html
:class="{ active: index === 0 }"
```

As shown in the [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax)

Comment: of course but i want when click on other button remove active of first button

Comment: I use it for just one button have active style  button:focus{
        background-color: $optional-red;
        color: #fff;
      }
but i want in default first button have this style

Comment: @faezeh if you have other conditions, just add them next to the index, for example `index === 0 && buttonNotClickedYet`.

Comment: what `buttonNotClickedYet`  means?

Comment: @faezeh it could be a computed that is triggered once you have once clicked on your button. Or any condition really.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure your `btnIndex` variable has 0 value by default.
So you can apply conditional class

```
:class="btnIndex == index ?'active':''"
```

Comment: of course but i want when click on other button remove active of first button ,I use it for just one button have active style button:focus{ background-color: $optional-red; color: #fff; } but i want in default first button have this style

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer. Please see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that completely without vuejs. Use simple CSS. Give the button a special class and then:

```
button.special {
 color: blue
}
button.special:first {
 color: red
}
```