# Why ''classList.add()'' method does not work in my Vuetify app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I was working in my Nuxt project that uses **Vuetify** as a framework until I noticed something strange. the following code is the code of one of my components:

```html
<template>
<section>
    <v-list>
        <v-list-item-group>
            <v-list-item
            v-for="(item, i) in subjects"
            :key="i"
            @click="activeClass"
            >
            <nuxt-link to="#">
                {{ item }}
            </nuxt-link>
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>

    <div id="myElem" @click="otherFunc"> 
      some text
    </div>
</section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
      return {
        subjects: ["تاریخی", "خلاقیت", "روان شناسی", "زندگی نامه", "مذهبی", "فیزیک", "ریاضیات"],
        }
    },

    methods: {

        activeClass: function(eve) {
        let allItems = document.querySelectorAll(".v-list-item");
        allItems.forEach(element => {
          element.classList.remove("classActiveRoute");
        });

        let tagClick = eve.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
        let mainElem = eve.target;
        if(tagClick == "a") {
          mainElem = eve.target.parentElement;
        }
        console.log(mainElem.classList)

        mainElem.classList.add("classActiveRoute")
        console.log(mainElem.classList)
        
        
      },

      otherFunc: function(eve2) {
        eve2.target.classList.add("classActiveRoute")
      }

    } // end of methods
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.classActiveRoute {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.theme--dark.v-list-item--active:hover::before {
 opacity: 0.08;
}

.theme--dark.v-list-item--active::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

#myElem {
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-color: #0f45af;
  min-height: 145px;
}

</style>
```

In that code I used ["Vuetify v-list"](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/list-item-groups/) to show a list of items. Because I wanted to disable the active styles of lists in other pages, I tried to add and remove my desired class with my own code. The code that does this task is in the **activeClass()** method. There I added class to "mainElem" element that is the parent of **"a"** tag in my list. I consoled the output before and after adding class and it shows the class was added:

[image]

But the "elements tab (or inspector tab in Firefox)" does not show class in the element:

[image]

To insure that my code is correct and the **Vuetify** does not allow the code to do its task, I added another "div" (div with `id="myElem"`) and add class to that "div" in another method, and it works correctly. My question here is that why we could not add class to "Vuetify" items in **v-list** with "classList.add()" method and how to resolve that?

Comment: I think you have to pass the event to the function `@click="otherFunc($event)"> `

Comment: You should not use any `querySelector` but append/remove it with state binding.

Comment: @kissu what do you mean by "state binding"? do you mean something like ```:class="{ active: isActive }"```, but that applies to all items not just one of them that was clicked? Also "querySelectorAll" that I used is for removing classes and I used the tag and event of vue itself

Comment: Yep, something like this. If you want specific elements, you can add a condition to it like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68741740/8816585

Comment: @kissu thanks for your comment, it helped me to understand something and resolve my problem, but could you briefly explain why my method does not work, or give me a link that explain to understand why it is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use DOM selectors, meanwhile Vue is state oriented, some it's not working as VanillaJS or jQuery in the matter than you don't need to target a node and make some changes on it to have reactive data.

If you can use a state to fix your issue, just do it like this.
Otherwise use [`$refs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) to target a specific element in your page.
It will be more Vue-y, will not have weird behavior with it being an SPA and will follow the guidelines of the documentation. Vue3 do also have reactive selectors.

So yeah `querySelector` is not the most powerful, not recommended and is mainly tied to the old fashioned way of using imperative code like jQuery did back in it's time.