# Is there a way to separate the element instance by three roles in NUXT JS?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am making use of nuxt.js. I am trying to display the pages of each role, in `data()` I have the value of the elements from where I have the routes (`items`), and with the use of `v-for` I am trying to separate them by roles, but I have not succeeded.

Somebody could help me?

This code **layouts/defauld.vue**

```html
<template>
  <v-app dark>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      :mini-variant="miniVariant"
      :clipped="clipped"
      fixed
      app
    >
      <v-list>
        <Avatar />
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, i) in items"
          :key="i"
          :to="item.to"
          router
          exact
        >
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title" />
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-app-bar :clipped-left="clipped" fixed app>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer" />
      <v-btn icon @click.stop="miniVariant = !miniVariant">
        <v-icon>mdi-{{ `chevron-${miniVariant ? "right" : "left"}` }}</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-spacer />
      <v-toolbar-title class="titulo1" v-text="title" />
    </v-app-bar>
    <!-- Contenido del Main -->
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <nuxt />
      </v-container>
    </v-main>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <v-footer :absolute="!fixed" app>
      <span>&copy; {{ new Date().getFullYear() }}</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Avatar from "~/components/Avatar";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      clipped: true,
      drawer: false,
      fixed: false,
      items: [
        {
          icon: "mdi-apps",
          title: "Iniciar sesión",
          to: "/IniciarSesion",
        },
        {
          icon: "mdi-apps",
          title: "Bienvenido",
          to: "/",
        },
        {
          icon: "mdi-apps",
          title: "Ver usuarios",
          to: "/_administrador/VerUsuarios",
        },
        {
          icon: "mdi-apps",
          title: "Lista de Ortomosaicos",
          to: "/_especialista/ListarOrtomosaicos",
        },
        {
          icon: "mdi-apps",
          title: "Cargar información",
          to: "/_especialista/CargarInformacion",
        },
        {
          icon: "mdi-apps",
          title: "Procesamiento",
          to: "/_especialista/Procesamiento",
        },
      ],
      miniVariant: false,
      right: true,
      rightDrawer: false,
      title: "El Potrero",
    };
  },
  components: {
    Avatar,
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.titulo1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
</style>
```

this is what is showing right now

[image]

and I want to get this
admin
[image]
expert
[image]
Another user
[image]

Comment: What did you tried so far? You'll need some `v-if` or `v-show` at some point here, if you want to hide things. And also have a way of filtering your data into clearly separated categories. Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68741697/8816585), but applied to whole blocks.

Comment: I need to separate the items into categories. For example: If the **admin** login, I want to only show the **items** from **home** `to: "/"`, **show users** `to: "/ _administrador / VerUsuario"`, etc. In NavBar
And the next  **expert**: the items are to: `"/_especialista/ListarOrtomosaicos"`  and `to: "/_especialista/CargarInformacion"`...

Comment: Hiding the options of who isn't currently connected.

Comment: Starting looking into how to filter in JavaScript.

Comment: thank you @kissu, change items `items: {'Admin': [], 'expert': [],...}` and add in `v-for = "(item, i) in items.key"` where `key = Admin, expert. ...` inside `v-list-item`. Is already solved