# Add/remove class on only one item in for loop (Vue)

Tags: css, vue.js, parent-child, watch, vue-props

I would like to add and remove a class from only one item at a time in a for loop. I have a bunch of dynamically loaded items, and once one of them is clicked, that item should have the class. When another item is clicked, the class should be removed from the previous item and added to the item that was just clicked.

This is the code I currently have. I can see that timeslot.selected is updated as it should, but the child component's :class is not reacting to the prop change at all.

**AvailableTimeslots.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <timeslot
            v-for="timeslot in timeslots"
            :key="timeslot.id"
            :timeslot="timeslot"
            @pickedTimeslot="pickTime(timeslot)"
        ></timeslot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Timeslot from './Timeslot.vue';

    export default {
        name: 'AvailableTimeslots',
        components: { Timeslot },
        data() {
            return {
                timeslots: []
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getTimeslots();
        },
        methods: {
            pickTime(timeslot) {
                this.deselectTimeslots(timeslot.id);
            },
            async getTimeslots() {
                // Gets timeslots (not relevant)

                this.deselectAllTimeslots();
            },
            deselectAllTimeslots() {
                this.timeslots.forEach(timeslot => {
                    timeslot.selected = false;
                });
            },
            deselectTimeslots(id) {
                this.timeslots.forEach(timeslot => {
                    if (timeslot.id !== id) timeslot.selected = false;
                    else timeslot.selected = true;
                });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Timeslot.vue**

```
<template>
    <div 
        class="card"
        :class="{ 'selected-timeslot': this.timeslot.selected }"
        @click="pickTime()"
    >
        {{ timeslot.from }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Timeslot',
        props: [ 'timeslot' ],
        methods: {
            pickTime() {
                this.$emit('pickedTimeslot', this.timeslot);
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

I have also tried copying over the value from timeslot.selected to a data attribute, but the same goes as before - when I watch the timeslot prop, nothing updates (even though the timeslot does in fact update if I check Vue DevTools).

**Timeslot.vue**

```
<template>
    <div 
        class="card"
        :class="{ 'selected-timeslot': this.isSelected }"
        @click="pickTime()"
    >
        {{ timeslot.from }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Timeslot',
        props: [ 'timeslot' ],
        data() {
            return {
                isSelected: this.timeslot.selected,
            };
        },
        methods: {
            pickTime() {
                this.$emit('pickedTimeslot', this.timeslot);
            },
        },
        watch: {
            timeslot: {
                handler() {
                    this.$nextTick(() => {
                        this.isSelected = this.timeslot.selected;
                    });
                },
                immediate: true,
                deep: true,
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

Anyone got any idea why the child component doesn't react on updates to the prop? Or even better - can I solve this in a simpler way?

Comment: Hi, please give a try to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68741740/8816585

Comment: In your timeslot.vue file you have the class referencing `this.timeslot.selected`, but in template you dont use `this`, you just reference `timeslot.selected`. Same for this.isSelected - should just be isSelected in the template area.